# Xml Dom Parsing in J2ME

Tags: java-me, xml-parsing, midp

In my J2ME Application, I can get the xml data as a string from Server, but I can't be able to read the tag and its elements through code. Please  suggest me some solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target device has [`JSR 172`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/ws/jsr172/index.html) you can use [`SAX`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/xmlparser-1354217.html) or `DOM`.
If not you can try [`kxml2`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/files/kxml2/). There is a nice introduction to it at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/XML_Parser_in_Java_ME