# Parse XML to object in J2me

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I have an String that contains Xml tag. which want to be convert from XML to Object in J2ME
so please anyone post some code for this. 
The string is String str=`BC1`Amruthesh G;

Comment: You can parse it first, then manually build your object yourself. For JavaME one of the most used parsers was [kXML2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/).

Comment: If your target device supports JSR 172 you can use SAX or DOM default parsers. See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858576/xml-dom-parsing-in-j2me/12874123#12874123